How to install a package from Artifact Registry in Google Cloud
I'm trying to use the command mentioned in the google docs to install a package directly from Artifact Registry: 
pip install --index-url https://europe-west3-python.pkg.dev/PROJECT_ID/vfde-py-dev/ UMMobile


I know that the package is there as I can see it:

For some reason I cannot install any package from this repository. I tried with a different one as well and also did not succeed. Is there something wrong with my command?
